# Create an internet-explorer plugin

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins

I'm having troubles finding resources on the net on how to create a plugin for IE (6 & 7). Do you happen to know good sites/tutorials on this subject?

BTW, here's why I want to do this: we have a web app here that's linked with another; i.e. when on a certain page, you could launch a bookmarklet (bookmark with javascript) that would parse the page and send data to the 2nd web app. This has worked fine for the last 2 years.

Now they want to update the application, and the information the bookmarklet used to retrieve are now spread on 2 pages.

So I intend the plugin to look for each url that is loaded, and if it fits a given pattern, then parse the page and store the data. If the second page is loaded (url pattern again), then make a button appear on the page that would launch the other web app with the retrieved data.

Do you see any problem with this? (bonus points: one of the 2 pages contains frames)

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/ieprogram/security/article.php/c11633__1/) is the sample of Browser Helper Object doing something similar. May be in your case the event will be DISPID_DOWNLOADBEGIN (as you want to catch any URI accessed, not only the ones entered by user).

Keep in mind that antivirus software doesn't like plugins like this because troyan programs often use similar way to record user's browsing history. May be a good idea is to consider doing this via AJAX.