# How can I read the rendered HTML of the current page in Internet Explorer using C#?

Tags: c#, html, browser

I checked different questions regarding accessing websites using c#. However, my question is a bit different. Is it possible to read the currently opened page in internet explorer using c# code?

The idea is to have a standalone application in c# that observes the currently opening IE page. So instead of accessing the page internally in the application, I just want to see, whatever page is open, and read the rendered html in it.

Comment: is this going to be a client app?

Comment: You can read the html of the currently rendered page; however, you cannot read the "rendered" html (what ever this means). What you probably need, is to access the object model of the actual page.

Comment: Isn't that what the IE dev tools are for?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to enumerate your IE windows and then to extract content from it. Smth like this. Import WinAPI f-tions to use in managed C# code:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className, IntPtr windowTitle);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);
```

And then simple list them:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
    // Loop all parent windows
    while((hWindow = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, hWindow, null, IntPtr.Zero)) != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        GetWindowText(hWindow, sb, sb.MaxCapacity);
        // Interested in Chrome only :)
        if( sb.ToString().Contains("Google Chrome") )
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Then you need to extract HTML from window. But I don't know how :)

Comment: the website should be rendered in a control which should be enumerable by GetChildWindows. could be worth a try calling the value property

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
static string GetHtmlPage(string strURL)
{

  String strResult;
  WebResponse objResponse;
  WebRequest objRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL);
  objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
  {
    strResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
  }
  return strResult;
}
```

Import these two namespaces:

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
```

Comment: The OP is asking about reading the DOM from an already open IE instance. Your answer does none of that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can communicate with IE from a separate Application.

You could embed a HTTP Request Response stream into an application you write, or even embed a browser into an application, I've done something similar using the Chromium browser which in effect replicates Chrome.

Never done it for IE

Answer (score 0):

Sounds tricky. I don't know what's the point of your application.
So, just some ideas coming to my mind:

You can try a [sniffer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17031/A-Network-Sniffer-in-C). This might work at least for non-encrypted connections.
So Quick-and-dirty: use a sniffer to find out the target page, call the page again in your application using e.g. the WebBrowser class and get the "rendered HTML" (do you mean "inner HTML"?) seperately.

Maybe it works also via a [IE plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316874/create-an-internet-explorer-plugin) which passes the html to your application?